# Django and PostgreSQL Full-Text Search: Some terms not found by search lookup

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search

I am using Django 2.0 and postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.6.1

I am having the below model with headline and body_text:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

The below is my content

```
headline: cheese making

body_text:

The simplest way to use full text search is to search a single term against a single column in the database. For example: >>> Entry.objects.filter(body_text__search='Cheese') [<Entry: Cheese on Toast recipes>, <Entry: Pizza Recipes>]. This creates a to_tsvector in the database from the body_text field and a plainto_tsquery ...
```

The following the search results using the the `search lookup`. I have added 'django.contrib.postgres' in INSTALLED_APPS.

```
Case 1: Works
In [1]: Entry.objects.filter(body_text__search='Cheese')
Out[1]: <QuerySet [<Entry: cheese making>]>

Case 2: Not working
In [2]: Entry.objects.filter(body_text__search='Pizza')
Out[2]: <QuerySet []>
(the word Pizza is there in the body_text still is not searching)

Case 3: Not working
In [3]: Entry.objects.filter(body_text__search='vector')
Out[3]: <QuerySet []>
(the word vector is there in to_tsvector

Case 4: Not working
In [9]: Entry.objects.filter(body_text__search='Entry')
Out[9]: <QuerySet []>

Case 5: Not working
In [10]: Entry.objects.filter(body_text__search='data')
Out[10]: <QuerySet []>
```

How to search for the terms which are not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We used the postgresql's full-text search module in django for some projects at work and I think that full text search is striping html tags from your Entry's body_text, and it strip `<Entry: Cheese on Toast recipes>, <Entry: Pizza Recipes>` because `<` and `>`.

I tried to apply `to_tsvector` on your example, with `<` and `>` and without them, and the resulting vectors are different:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/9296)

```
SELECT to_tsvector('The simplest way to use full text search is to search a single term against a single column in the database. For example: >>> Entry.objects.filter(body_text__search=''Cheese'') [<Entry: Cheese on Toast recipes>, <Entry: Pizza Recipes>]. This creates a to_tsvector in the database from the body_text field and a plainto_tsquery ...');
```

> 'bodi':25,39 'chees':28 'column':18 'creat':30 'databas':21,36
>   'entry.objects.filter':24 'exampl':23 'field':41 'full':6 'plainto':44
>   'search':8,11,27 'simplest':2 'singl':13,17 'term':14 'text':7,26,40
>   'tsqueri':45 'tsvector':33 'use':5 'way':3

```
SELECT to_tsvector('The simplest way to use full text search is to search a single term against a single column in the database. For example: >>> Entry.objects.filter(body_text__search=''Cheese'') [Entry: Cheese on Toast recipes, Entry: Pizza Recipes]. This creates a to_tsvector in the database from the body_text field and a plainto_tsquery ...');
```

> 'bodi':25,47 'chees':28,30 'column':18 'creat':38 'databas':21,44
>   'entri':29,34 'entry.objects.filter':24 'exampl':23 'field':49
>   'full':6 'pizza':35 'plainto':52 'recip':33,36 'search':8,11,27
>   'simplest':2 'singl':13,17 'term':14 'text':7,26,48 'toast':32
>   'tsqueri':53 'tsvector':41 'use':5 'way':3

So try your query removing `<` and `>` from your `body_text`.

## Note

"to_tsvector" is a PostgreSQL function for converting a document to the tsvector data type.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/textsearch-controls.html

The django.contrib.postgres use it internally to provide the search lookup ( `__search` )

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#the-search-lookup

Comment: "to_tsvector" is this a table in my database. Can we see it. I am little new to this thing.

Comment: what about case5 or part of word search

Comment: "to_tsvector" is a PostgreSQL function for converting a document to the tsvector data type.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/textsearch-controls.html

The django.contrib.postgres use it internally to provide `__search`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#the-search-lookup

Comment: Django uses plainto_tsquery() function, not to_tsquery(): So how to do partial search like "chee" instead of "cheese" it should get the words

Comment: As you can read in the official documentation I linked _"This creates a to_tsvector in the database from the body_text field and a plainto_tsquery from the search term 'Cheese', both using the default database search configuration. The results are obtained by matching the query and the vector."_ So `plainto_tsquery()` is used for your query text and `to_tsvector` is used for your `body_text`

Comment: how to do this using to_tsvector with SQL in DJANGO

Comment: Django use it under the hood when you use the search lookup.
See the official documentation for detail https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#the-search-lookup

Comment: Sorry i wanted to know how to use to_tsquery() instead of plain so that i can have partial search functionality